# The config setting Basic cannot be changed because is controlled by policies

Tags: group-policy, winrm

Im trying to enable basic authentication on Windows Server with command winrm set winrm/config/client/auth '@{Basic="true"}'

I get an error saying The config setting Basic cannot be changed because is controlled by policies. The policy would need to be set to "Not Configured" in order to change the config setting.

Ive checked my group policies and they are already set to "Not Configured". What else could I be missing?

Comment: So... are you reposting a post that got deleted? Why did you delete it?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/841689/changing-winrm-settings-from-script

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66523685/winrm-cannot-process-the-request-controlled-by-policy-server

Comment: @Gantendo i had posted it on stack overflow and they suggested posting it here. So I deleted it on stack overflow and copy the post here but didnt notice it appended that comment

Comment: I tried the solution in the two links but none of that worked for me

Comment: Check if `hklm:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WinRM\Client` has the value `AllowBasic` disabled. You can try to delete it, run gpupdate, and check whether it comes back. If it does, then you have a GPO setting somewhere.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale okay i was able to set it to true in the registry editor

Comment: Try the command `winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Basic="true"}'`. To check whether basic authentication is allowed run `winrm get winrm/config/service`. See [link](https://docs.vmware.com/en/vRealize-Orchestrator/8.11/com.vmware.vrealize.orchestrator-use-plugins.doc/GUID-D4ACA4EF-D018-448A-866A-DECDDA5CC3C1.html).